# Apache HTTPD: URL resolution for a virtual host with proxies and directory alias

Tags: proxy, virtualhost, httpd, static-files, conf

Here's what my environment looks like:

- **REST api** (django), running over WSGI (mod_wsgi) on port `http://server:8107/api`
- **static files** for the API site (i have some admin pages), in a directory, say `/opt/wsgi/staticfiles/subdomain`
- **Web application** (expressjs), running over pm2/nodejs, on `http://server:3002/`

I need to group all this under a virtualhost on port 80 as follows:

- http://subdomain.server/api : the rest API
- http://subdomain.server/api/static : the static files needed by the API site
- http://subdomain.server/ : the web application

Here is the relevant part of the configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName subdomain.server
    ServerAlias subdomain.server.local

    Alias /api/static/ /opt/wsgi/staticfiles/subdomain/
    <Directory /opt/wsgi/staticfiles/subdomain/ >
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        Options -Indexes
        IndexOptions Charset=UTF-8
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass /api http://127.0.0.1:8107/api
    ProxyPassReverse /api http://127.0.0.1:8107/api

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3002/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3002/

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when I try to access a static resource (let's say for example `/api/static/js/jquery.js`) i find that the url is not resolved first by the Alias directive, but rather passed to the WSGI app (`/api`), which then obviously fires a 404 error.

Re-ordering the directives does not seem to have any effect.

What should I change to ensure HTTPD will serve `/api/static` before anything else?

> *EDIT*: I run Apache HTTPD 2.2.15 under a CentOS 6.5 distro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following conf is what you are looking for :

```
ProxyPass /api/static !
```

It tells Apache to not take this path into account when routing stuff to your proxied application, so it can be dealt with other kind of access (here your Alias directive).

Comment: Works like a charm!